# on board kinect use for navigation

Tags: ros, kinect, odroid, 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the kinect for xbox one or kinect for windows 2, which one is better for uav navigation? I know the Kinect for windows is discontinued right now. I want to use odroid xu4 as onboard computer to connect kinect.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217453/on-board-kinect-use-for-navigation/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using kinect 2 for windows. According to [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) and [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) , I can process data successfully in odroid xu4 board.

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [breadplex](https://answers.ros.org/users/45942/breadplex/) on 2019-09-21**:
How many FPS does it produce? Just I read for 30 FPS Kinect need very powerfull board.